# Tensor Flow CCTV IP Camera

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I have compiled an object deteection system using TensorFlow on a Windows 10 Machine, using Python 3.6. The model works with my Web Cam as well as a video stored on my PC.

I have attemped to get a feed from an IP CCTV camera as below:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://username:password@camera ip")
```

This results in the error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Could someone please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you update the question with some more information related to code and error

Comment: Did you print `cap`? I guess your code is broken and `cap` is just `None`.

Answer (score 1):

usually the cctv camera support rtsp protocol, you should wirte the code like this:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:hik12345@10.199.27.123:554')
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video output', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)& 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```